# Using to_date with Spark SQL, getting parseexception error

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to convert a string value from JSON to date. Example value is 2022-11-15T08:45:36.905-0800.  I'm using the code below but getting ParseException: Any ideas? I believe 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ' is the right format for the date example listed above, but could be wrong?

```
    df_3.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
    spark.sql("select to_date('create_dt', 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ') as testdt2 from 
    test").show(n=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. First, `to_date` expects a column as the first argument, and you are passing a string (`'create_dt'`), so you can fix that by removing the quotes and leave it as `created_dt`
2. You are declaring your second argument, which is a string, in single quotes, just as `T`; you need to escape that (`'yyyy-MM-dd\\'\\T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ'`)

The final looks of the code:

```scala
spark.sql("select to_date(create_dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ') as testdt2 from test")
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|testdt2   |
+----------+
|2022-11-15|
+----------+
```

Good luck!